# Rephrasing without using because

Tags: word-usage, phrase-request

Can this statement be rephrased without using the word "because" or sounding elegant

> The fee is discounted substantially because organizations are expected
>   to have a long term contract, a minimum of a year.

Comment: I find *as* as the best replacement for *because* in most of the cases! :)

Comment: I find " for" to be a possibility as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The fee is discounted substantially because organizations are expected to have a long term contract, a minimum of a year.

You could use *since*:

> The fee is discounted substantially **since** organizations are expected to have a long term contract, with the (a? its?) term lasting a year or more.

Answer (score 0):

> **The fee is discounted substantially when there is a long term contract**
>   **of at least one year.**

Comment: That rephrasing implies that there are short term contracts, which the original doesn't. Granted with more context, that sentence might fit what the poster is trying to communicate. The single sentence alone reads more like a justification of why the fee is discounted than a statement that the fee is discounted.

Comment: "expected" does not imply only long term.  It would need to say "must have"

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can be written without the coordinating conjunction "because":

> The fee is discounted substantially **due to the fact that**
>   organizations will have a long term contract, a minimum of a year.

Comment: "due to the fact that" is just a longer way of saying "because", it is not an improvement and isn't more elegant.